# Changing the cursor in a C++ game

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d, 2d-games

I'm currently creating a 2D game using C++ and OpenGL. I was wondering whether anyone could explain the best way to change the current cursor from the mouse icon. I am creating a top down shooting game and therefore would like the cursor to be displayed as a crosshair instead.

Comment: You probably need to provide more details about your platform.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use your OS-specific function for manually changing the mouse pointer icon (and the "hot point" of that icon), or you can use the OS-specific functions for hiding the mouse pointer, and manually drawing your own image using the last mouse-move event that your application received.

Alternatively, instead of using OS-specific functions, you can use a cross-platform API that wraps those kinds of functions for you (SDL, SFML, Qt, to name a few).

OpenGL doesn't have any functions that specifically operate on mouse pointers - that'd be a windowing API thing, not a 3D graphics thing. OpenGL *only* deals with drawing graphics.

If you are using GLUT (which isn't 'OpenGL' but an add-on library), you can call:

```
glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
```

Comment: How do I include the GLUT library?

Comment: That's a different question that depends on what IDE you are using, and what compiler. Programming requires you to give alot of details when asking questions. =) Answers vary depending on alot of different things. Personally, I wouldn't use GLUT anyway - I recommend the use of the latest [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) libraries. Using the latest SDL or SFML, you actually wouldn't even *need* OpenGL to do 2D graphics - but you can optionally still use OpenGL with SDL or SFML if you wanted to.

Comment: @edwoollard: If you have to ask "how to include GLUT", then you're misguided. GLUT is just one of the available frameworks, but there are others. You must, of course, use the functions of the framework you use for the rest of your program. So first things first, tell us which framework you're using (if you don't know, please get yourself familiar with that before doing and further development work), then we can tell you, which function to use.

Comment: @datenwolf I was under the impression that you could use your standard framework but also use other functions from other frameworks by just including them like: #include "glut.h". Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @edwoollard: You're wrong insofar that the cursor visible is a property of the window the mouse pointer is over and windows are created **and** managed by a framework. A window created by say SDL is managed by SDL and is completely inaccessible to, say, an included GLUT framework. Also it's a really bad idea to mix frameworks in a single application. Bad things can happen. Also `#include` does not "add" a framework or library. Essentially include files are kind of "table of contents" without the actual thing attached. Getting the actual functionality happens by linking.